# Slick library w/ Play - date type incompatibility?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, slick

I'm running into a compatibility problem under Scala while using Slick and Play. I'm attempting to use the Date type in one of my model schema via Slick, and then make that date available in a form in Play:

Model:

```
case class Test(id: Int, date: java.sql.Date)
class Tests(tag: Tag) extends Table[Test](tag, "Tests") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def date = column[java.sql.Date]("date")
  def * = (id, date) <> (Test.tupled, Test.unapply)
}
```

Controller form element:

```
def testForm: Form[Test] = {
  Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> number,
    "date" -> date)(Test.apply)(Test.unapply)))
}
```

However, the form has a compilation error, because Slick uses java.sql.Date, while Play uses java.util.Date:

```
"type mismatch; found : (Int, java.sql.Date) => models.Test required: (Int,  java.util.Date) => ?"
```

Is there any built-in support that Slick or Play provides for proper interoperability, or do you have to manually convert between them? How/where would this best be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play supports java.sql.Date, you just need to do the mapping as

```
def testForm: Form[Test] = {
    Form(
    mapping(
        "id" -> number,
        "date" -> sqlDate)(Test.apply)(Test.unapply)))
}
```

Note that I haven't tested it, but [the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms%24) show that `sqlDate` exists.

Another option would be to define a type mapping between java.util.Date and java.sql.Date in slick. Look [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/userdefined.html#scalar-types) to see how.

Also, if you haven't yet, look at [joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or some [scala wrapper](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time). It will probably make working with dates and times easier.

Comment: This solved the problem... I could have sworn I tried sqlDate at some point, but I must have had an error somewhere else. Thanks for the answer, and for the tip on joda time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jodaDate mapping in the form. Also use joda DateTime in the model as well as table column and define an implicit joda to sql mapper.

```scala
def testForm: Form[Test] = {
  Form(
    mapping(
      "id" -> number,
       "date" -> jodaDate)(Test.apply)(Test.unapply)
  )

import org.joda.time.DateTime
import java.sql.Timestamp
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._  // I suppose you are using play-slick (https://github.com/freekh/play-slick) plugin


object JodaToSqlMapper {
  implicit val dateTimeToDate = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
    dateTime => new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis),
    timestamp => new DateTime(timestamp))
}

case class Test(id: Int, date: org.joda.time.DateTime)

import JodaToSqlMapper._

class Tests(tag: Tag) extends Table[Test](tag, "Tests") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def date = column[DateTime]("date")
  def * = (id, date) <> (Test.tupled, Test.unapply _)
}
```